# Android service,thread and notification

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service

In my app on OnCreate() method, I made a service;
in the service,I made a thread in which I am starting a socket.

It seems ok with the flow : App runs , service starts -> thread starts -> socket starts and in thread , in while(true) loop I check socket for incoming data,
when I received the specific data I will generate a notification.
Notification fires but app crashes.

I gave the vibrate permission and introduced service to Androidmanifest file
here is my notification code :

```
public void MakeNotification()
{
//      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//      PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification notify = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Taxi Driver")
            .setContentText("New Mission")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();
    notify.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notify.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
              getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

    notificationManager.notify(0,notify);
    Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Any information would be great.
I have one assumption. is crashes happens because I made notification from another thread ??

Comment: and you cannot verify that by yourself? call `notify` from the base UI thread and see if it made any difference...

Comment: What is your logcat saying?

Answer (score 0):

tthe problem solved.

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530293/can-noticationmanager-notify-be-called-from-a-worker-thread) it's possible to fire a notification from another thread than UI.

so my problem was just calling `Toast.makeText` from a worker thread [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821878/how-to-use-toast-message-inside-thread-in-android)

i removed it and it worked well