# Notifications not working on Api 27(8.1.0)

Tags: android, push-notification

Notifications are working for Oreo 8.0(Api 26) and below perfectly fine  but they are not working with Oreo 8.1.0.

below is the stack trace of an error

```
 android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 actions=2 vis=PRIVATE)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I am creating Notification channel for Oreo still it's not working for Oreo 8.1.0. I also refer other stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531742/startforeground-fail-after-upgrade-to-android-8-1) but not getting any clue why this error occuring in my case.

UpdateAlarmActivity.java

```
public class UpcomingAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "UpcomingAlarmReceiver";
    public static final String ACTION_DISMISS_NOW = "com.funswitch.funrooster.action.DISMISS_NOW";
    public static final String ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION = "com.funswitch.funrooster.action.CANCEL_NOTIFICATION";
    public static final String ACTION_SHOW_SNOOZING = "com.funswitch.funrooster.action.SHOW_SNOOZING";
    public static final String EXTRA_ALARM = "com.funswitch.funrooster.extra.ALARM";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION";
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "io.funswitch.funrooster.Channel";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final byte[] alarmBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra(EXTRA_ALARM);
        // Un-marshall the bytes into a parcel and create our Alarm with it.
        final Alarm alarm = ParcelableUtil.unmarshall(alarmBytes, Alarm.CREATOR);
        if (alarm == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No alarm received");
        }
        final long id = alarm.getId();
        final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean actionShowSnoozing = ACTION_SHOW_SNOOZING.equals(intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction() == null || actionShowSnoozing) {
            // Prepare notification
            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/15803726/5055032
            // Notifications aren't updated on the UI thread, so we could have
            // done this in the background. However, no lengthy operations are
            // done here, so doing so is a premature optimization.
            String title;
            String text;
            if (actionShowSnoozing) {
                if (!alarm.isSnoozed()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can't show snoozing notif. if alarm not snoozed!");
                }
                title = alarm.getLabel().isEmpty() ? context.getString(R.string.alarm) : alarm.getLabel();
                text = context.getString(R.string.title_snoozing_until,
                        formatTime(context, alarm.snoozingUntil()));
            } else {
                // No intent action required for default behavior
                title = context.getString(R.string.upcoming_alarm);
                text = formatTime(context, alarm.ringsAt());
            }
            Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(context, UpcomingAlarmReceiver.class)
                    .setAction(ACTION_DISMISS_NOW)
                    .putExtra(EXTRA_ALARM, ParcelableUtil.marshall(alarm));
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) id,
                    dismissIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            mBuilder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_dismiss_alarm_24dp,
                            context.getString(R.string.dismiss_now), piDismiss);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
                notificationChannel.setShowBadge(false);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                assert nm != null;
                mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                nm.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            Objects.requireNonNull(nm).notify(TAG, (int) id, mBuilder.build());
        } else if (ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(nm).cancel(TAG, (int) id);
        } else if (ACTION_DISMISS_NOW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            new AlarmController(context, null).cancelAlarm(alarm, false, true);
        }


    }
}
```

Above is my Java class where I am implementing the code for Notifications. Please help me out or give me some suggestions how can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In api level 27 google changed the notification methods now in api 27 or upper level you need to create notification channel to send notification.

Channel is categories all types of notifications learn more about notification channel

[check this](https://medium.com/cr8resume/notification-in-android-8-0-oreo-implementing-notification-channels-d65b0f81ca50) for notification channel

```
**if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   String id = "id_product";
   // The user-visible name of the channel.
   CharSequence name = "Product";
   // The user-visible description of the channel.
   String description = "Notifications regarding our products";
   int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
   NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
   // Configure the notification channel.
   mChannel.setDescription(description);
   mChannel.enableLights(true);
   // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
   // channel, if the device supports this feature.
   mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
   notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}**
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already go through the link you provided and I also created notification channel too. It's shown in my code above but it's not working.

Comment: change build .gradle compileSdkVersion 27 to 26 and Build Tools version (26.0.2) will help to send notification on app OnDestroy and onPause

Comment: Its working but sometimes it is causing run time exceptions I it is not a good way to do that because libray version shoulld alwayes be latest

Comment: Which kind of runtime exception, please explain

Comment: Like dex conflicts and showing deprecated api's in the build.gradle

Comment: am using vivo v9 oreo 8.1.0..i cant get fcm device id.do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Change your NotificationCompat.Builder constructor:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
```

adding the channel id:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I tried that but still now working. Notifications are working on Oreo 8.0 but not working on Oreo 8.1.0.

Comment: am using vivo v9 oreo 8.1.0..i cant get fcm device id.do you have any idea?